# Javascript/React: How do I access data in another class' constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two classes, the first one producing an array. How do I access it in another class?

```
class DataList {
    constructor(){
        this.dataArr = [] // An array

        this.size = this.dataArr.length;
    }

    getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
}
... continues
```

Below this, I have a react component(A table - but that's irrelevant for now):

```
class AssetTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._dataList = new DataList();

        this.state = {
            filteredDataList: this._dataList,
        };
 ... continues
```

I want to initiate the array of the constructor of the DataList class(dataArr) and start it as `new DataList()`; - but I'm failing to retrieve the input in the react component.

So the main question is, how do I access an array inside a class constructor, in another class(in this case, a react component)?

Comment: It's odd, because you expose a different class property via `getSize()` and don't see the equivalence?

Comment: By default, every property in JavaScript object is public. So if the object is instantiated by constructor function(in this case, class), you can access the property simply just use dot notation like: this._dataList.dataArr;

Comment: @modernator With the caveat that this reaches into the class internals, which may change.

Comment: @DaveNewton Technically class is just syntax sugar for constructor, so it's almost same with using constructor, nothing different. Every class syntax easily convert to constructor syntax also.

Comment: It's from an example used by Facebook. I'm still trying to learn how to create components and classes this way.

Comment: @modernator Yes, but that's an unrelated observation. Classes are the same thing, but provide structure, meaning, and semantics.

Comment: @modernator doing so leaves me with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataArr' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure that DataList class inside of AssetTable class is same DataList class as your first wrote? I tried with Node.js Repl, and it works.

Comment: Try this. It's almost same of your code, it works: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=class%20DataList%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.dataArr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20list%20%3D%20new%20DataList()%3B%0Aconsole.log(list.dataArr)%3B